# Как сделать так чтобы когда я наводил мышку на какой-то он менял форму или цвет на django

Tags: python-3.x

Здраствуйте. я новичок на Django и я хотел сделать так чтобы когда я наводил мышку на какой-то компонент он менял цвет или форму на Django

Answer (score 2):

Джанга не контролирует страницу после того как её отдала.

В данном случае нужно добавить `css` с селектором `:hover` на ваш элемент.

Можно записать прямо в шаблоне:

```
<div>
    <style type="text/css" scoped>
      #changecolor:hover {
        background-color: yellow;
      }    
    </style>
    <div id=changecolor>
      blabla
    </div>
</div>
```

где changecolor имя объекта. Если объектов несколько используй class